# Bundle PDF with eBook reader to iPhone app

Tags: iphone, pdf

I have a customer who wants her local newspaper (.pdf) published as an native iPhone app. I tried to talk her out of it but she wants it to "be cool, with trend and with fancy page flipping - native iPhone app" (...and who ever pays the bills right :/) Nevertheless, is there an easy one-click solution to bundle the PDF with a simple eBook reader and create a XCode project or native app I can upload to the AppStore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears this is called an "eBook framework" or "tablet publishing"

free:

- [Leaves](https://github.com/brow/leaves)
  which supports PDF and page flip, very beta, forks support zoom and orientation (vergy buggy)
- [Baker Framework](http://bakerframework.com)
  which supports HTML5 and CSS3 animations (also see the Laker fork)

commercial:

- [Apperplace](http://apperplace.com) 100$, uses images instead of PDF
- [FastPDFKit](http://mobfarm.eu/fastpdfkit) ~1000$
- [TurnPage](http://turn-page.com/online-interactive-publications/products_overview.php) ~1000$
- [WrApps](http://www.mygazines.com/pricing_wrapps) ~2000$
- [TouchbooksReader](http://www.touchbooksreader.com) ~ 5000$
- [Pixelmags](http://pixelmags.com)
- [RareWire](http://www.rarewire.com)
- [WoodWing](http://www.woodwing.com/en/digital-magazine/ipad-now)
- [Texterity](http://www.texterity.com/iphone_ipad_samples)

also have a look [at](http://blog.gilbertconsulting.com/2010/12/magazine-publishing-on-ipad.html) [this](http://indesignsecrets.com/turning-indesign-files-to-ipad-apps.php), it appears that Adobe and Quark Xpress support iPad publishing too.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a UIWebView to load a pdf - if the pdfs are huge then performance is poor but you might want to experiment thus -

```
//snippet - wont work without setting up some ivars n the like
NSString* pdfPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YOUR PDF FILE NAME" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfPath];
NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```