# Saving/showing PDF in the app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, pdf

I have a URL which returns a PDF document. Typically on the web browser this would open a dialog box asking me to either open or save the PDF document. Any ideas how to work this out on the native app? Or is a change needed at the server end whereby it already has the URL to display the PDF instead of open/save? I need to display the PDF on the native app. But how do I go about the first step of the URL asking me to open/save?

Any broad ideas/high level outline of the workflow in a native app w.r.t the above use case would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT: I guess the question wasn't clear enough. I am aware of how to render a PDF from the app directory or straight from a URL. The problem is the URL in this case gives out a open/save dialog box on the web browser. How do I handle that and choose to open/save it on a webview or the app directory? Or is that a use case not possible on iOS and hence is a change needed to my server side which generates the PDF and shows it directly instead of asking the user to open/save?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using a UIWebView to load the PDF request with scalesPageToFit set as YES. Worked.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

Re the URL

In your plist file you can specify which URLs you wish your app to respond to
[image: updated with a better screengrab]

Then in your appDelegate you need to implement a method to do something with the URL.

Something llike

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"specialwebsite"]) 
    {
```

OLD MISGUIDED ANSWER

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056537/bundle-pdf-with-ebook-reader-to-iphone-app/6056738#6056738) answer is pretty close to your requirements